# AngularJS wait unitl variable has changed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

(I changed title to be more accurate of current problem)

I am trying to add people to assignments from a client side peoplepicker, the problem is that in order to add them, I need the id of the person, and I don't know how to get this Id inside a $scope object.

This is the code to get the info, and the id of a person:

```
function getUserInfo() {

// Get the people picker object from the page.
var peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

// Get information about all users.
var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
var userInfo = '';
for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
    var user = users[i];
    for (var userProperty in user) { 
        userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
    }
}
$('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

// Get user keys.
var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
$('#userKeys').html(keys);

// Get the first user's ID by using the login name.
getUserId(users[0].Key);
}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {
var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
context.load(this.user);
context.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess), 
     Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
);
}

function ensureUserSuccess() {
$('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

My problem is that I have no idea as to what is going on inside the 'getUserId' function, how can I use this function to get the id of a person inside a $scope object, so that I later can send it with additional information to the SharePoint list?

This is the example from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593.aspx

I looked into using a service, and I ran into the same problem there, the difference is, now I know sort of what the problem is. But let's say I don't use a service, if I just use a variable, so I initiate the variable like so:

```
var userId;
```

and then inside the 'ensureUserSuccess()' function I do:

```
userId = this.user.get_id();
```

and lastly, in my $onSave function, I set the $scope.user.id to the userId variable. (The onSave function is to save this item to the SharePoint list)

This works the second time I try to save the item, the first time I do it, the userId variable is undefined, but if I try to save it again, it is not. In my onSave function, I have this:

```
getUserInfo();
$scope.user.id = userId;
```

In my head, I like to belive that the 'getUserInfo' function is finished before setting the $scope.user.id to the userId variable, but now I firmly belive that this is where the problem is, how can I wait with setting the user.id until that function has finished?

Comment: Basicly the ensureUserSuccess() is the function called when the query is successful. Instead of `$('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());` you could do: `$scope.userId = this.user.get_id();` I guess. This would put the id in a scope object

Comment: I thought so too, but that function is out of reach of the $scope, it's not defined there. Maybe i could rewrite the 'getUserId' to return the id? So I could call it like: $scope.User.Id = getUserId(loginName); , but I'm not sure how

Comment: You could create a service and in the ensureUserSuccess() function you set userId in that service, something like: `userService.set(this.user.get_id())`. Then create a get function in your service aswell, and do like: `$scope.user.id = userService.get();`

Comment: Okey, I will try that, I will get back to you later if I made it work or not

Comment: @Guinn I have updated the question with some new thoughts, mind to take a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, so my original question was about how to be able to set the ID of a user from the peoplepicker to a $scope object.

What I found is that the function 'initializePeoplePicker', has a callback function:

```
schema['OnUserResolvedClientScript'] = function(){
      getUserInfo();
};
```

Doing this solved my problem, this function fires each time a user is resolved, then I set the user id to the variable and then to the $scope object just before saving it.

Comment: I was on a holiday, glad you found the answer in the meantime :)